Is it possible to show the convexity of $f(x)$ by removing one of the hypotheses
I just solved an exercises which stated to show $f$ is strictly convex in $(-1, 1)$, knowing that $f: (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is: continuous, positive and at least twice differentiable everywhere. Also $f'(x) = 2xf^2(x)$.
Now this was easy since
$$f''(x) = 2f^2(x) + 4xf(x)f'(x) = 2f^2(x)\big(1 + 4f(x)\big)$$
Since $f$ is positive, everything is positive hence the thesis.

Is it possible to show $f$ is strictly convex by removing the "at least twice differentiability" of the function? Let's just suppose $f$ has all the above properties except for that one, something like (if it makes sense)

$$f(x) \quad \text{is such that} \quad f'(x) = 2xf^2(x) \quad \text{but} \quad f''(x) \quad \text{not guaranteed to exist}$$
So $f$ is a weird function such that $f''$ might not exist (for choice maybe).
Would it be possible to show convexity in this case?

If $f$ is once differentiable and $f'$ is given by the formula above, then $f$ is smooth, so the twice differentiable hypothesis is redundant.

@copper.hat We do not take the concept of smoothness in the game..

My point is that the second differentiable hypothesis is redundant, so proving it without is just more work than necessary.

@copper.hat My professor often gives exercises where we cannot take the existence of derivatives for granted. Hence I thought to see if in this case I could conclude too without $f''$

If $f:(-1, 1) \to \Bbb R$ is positive and differentiable with $f'(x) = 2xf^2(x)$ then $f$ is stricly convex.
You can first show that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-1, 0]$ and strictly increasing on $[0, 1)$. Then conclude that $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(-1, 1)$, which implies that $f$ is stricly convex.
If $f$ is just non-negative then one can still conclude that $f$ is (weakly) convex.
The nonnegativity condition can not be omitted, since $f(x) = -1/(1+x^2)$ satisfies the differential equation and is not convex on $(-1, 1)$.

I was also thinking: if I omitted the positivity condition, could I replace it with saying $f$ is bounded? Of course there must exist a rightful bounding. For example $|f| < \frac{1}{3}$ does not guarantee convexity, whereas $|f| < \frac{1}{4}$ does. Is this correct? (Always maintaining $f' = 2xf^2)$
Thank you for the answer!

Maybe I'm wrong but with the hypotheses of the existence of $f''$ and the direct calculation I would get
$$f''(x) = 2f^2(x)\left(1 + 4f(x)\right)$$
Hence $f''(x) > 0$ iff $1 + 4f(x) > 0$, that is $f(x) > -\frac{1}{4}$.
So saying $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{4}$ should be right...?

@J.N.: Isn't there a factor $x^2$ missing on the right-hand side?

Ops, you're right! Does the result hold the same though? $x^2 \geq 0$...

Maybe I can just "refine" the argument, saying $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{4x^2}$ :D

Most probably the positivy condition can be relaxed, but I do not have a better answer right now.

I'm sorry, just a question about your main answer: when I asked if possible to prove convexity by removing the existence of $f''$ you told me "then you show $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(-1, 1)$", but how do I do that without knowing that $f''$ is always positive, not knowing if $f''$ exists or not?

@J.N.: For $x > 0$ is $f'(x) = 2xf^2(x) \ge 0$ so that $f$ is increasing.  It follows that $f'$ is increasing as the product of two positive and increasing functions.. – For $x < 0$ the argument is similar.

@J.N.: For $x < 0$ you have that  $-f'(x) = 2 (-x) f^2(x)$ is decreasing as the product of two positive and decreasing functions, so that $f'$ is increasing.

I found that of all the function that satisfy the differential equation $f' = 2xf^2$, which are of the form $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2+k}$ for $k$ real, there is a "special" one which is non positive but convex in $(-1, 1)$, and it's $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2+3}$. For this function the inflection points are exactly $x = \pm 1$. Still thinking about how to relax positivity...

Tell me if this sounds right or incomplete or wrong: from what I said above, I could relax positivity by asking that $1 + 4x^2f(x) > 0$ that is $f(x) > -\frac{1}{4x^2}$.
Now I know that every function of the form $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2+a}$ satisfies the DE above. Hence I need to ask that
$$-\frac{1}{x^2+a} > -\frac{1}{4x^2} \implies \frac{3x^2-a}{4x^2(x^2+a)} < 0$$
The only case of interest is when $a > 0$.
This is satisfied if $x \in \left(-\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\right)$.
Is it a coincidence that I need $a = 3$, being $f: (-1, 1)$? This leads to the above comment
